# How to call function on unload of frame in body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

There are frame in document body tag. When page got refresh frame will be unload automatically. and I want to call a function which should be called when frame unload.

I have trigger event while frame unload but I don't know what's problem are going on there.

```
window.frames["147compose"].onunload = function(e) {
    $("a#147 .closeTab").trigger("click");
}
```

Here a tag is a link on which click event frame will pass data to other page using ajax. and 147compose is an frame id, and 147 is an id of a tag. where it is a link to send data from frame.

Comment: What is `f_id` and where is it defined? Your frame identifier is `frame_id`, should they be the same variable?

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to go into the frame and do things with other things then its document.

in the iframe:

```
function BindOnUnload(inputFunction){
  window.onunload=inputFunction;
}
document.BindOnUnload=BindOnUnload;
```

in the parrent:

```
iframe = //get your iframe here;
iframe.contentDocument.BindOnUnload(/*yourfunctionhere*/);
```